# unity animator and ANY STATE issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

hey guys i have a problem with the animator i made a player that can transform so (player animations = idle; run; slid; jump ===plus=== player trasform animation = trasform; idlePlayerAfterTransform; runPlayerAfterTransform; slidPlayerAfterTransform; jumpPlayerAfterTransform) and i add testing attack animation and attack idle . the problem is I followed a tutorial and I use the ANYSTATE as the base of a relationship between all the animation and when I add the trasform animation they don't work and attack animation too I don't know what to do I really stuck I here am the script for animation manager

[image]

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private inputStates inputSs;
    private walk walkB;
    private Animator anim;
    private CollisionState CS;
    private wallJump wallj;
    private Jump longJ;

    public bool attack;


    public int lastPressed = 0;


    void Awake()
    {
        inputSs = GetComponent<inputStates> ();
        walkB = GetComponent<walk> ();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        CS = GetComponent<CollisionState> ();
        wallj = GetComponent<wallJump> ();
        longJ = GetComponent<Jump> ();
    }
    void Start () {
    }
    void Update () {
        //DOZENT WORK =====================================================
        if (CS.standing && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Alpha1)) {     
            attack = true;
            AnimState (2);

            if (CS.standing && attack) {
                attack = false;
            }
        }
        //==================================================

        anim.SetFloat ("Vspeed", GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);
        //IDLE=========================
        if (CS.standing && !attack) {
            AnimState(0);
        }
        //=============================

        //run animation=====================
        if (inputSs.absX > 0 && !attack) {
            AnimState(1);

        }
        //==================================


        //slid============================
        if (!CS.standing && CS.wall) {

            AnimState(3);
        }
        //================================

        //falling & jump =========================
        if (!CS.standing && !CS.wall && !attack) {
            AnimState(5);
        }
        //================================

        //run animation speed=======================
        anim.speed = walkB.running ? walkB.runM : 1;
        //=========================================
    }

    void AnimState(int value){

        anim.SetInteger ("animS", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: When any animation state like (idle ,attack,run) the grey ones i mean, is completed, are they returning to ANY STATE (the bluish one)?

Comment: the animations (run,slide,and jump(blendtree)) are returning to ANYSTATE and working fine the problem is when i add the others animation as you see in the picture they doesn't work even if i activate them throw the script they just doesn't work and always return to the default state (idle) but for the (jump and slid animation )they are working perfectly fine i dont know why??